# Ubuntu boot freeze due to blacklist: problem blacklisting hash (-13)

Tags: boot, kernel, bios, msi

I am using MSI machine with UEFI mode, Secure boot disabled, fast boot disabled. When I try to start Ubuntu 22.04 LTS from my SSD I am getting below error during boot.

```
Motherboard - MAG Z690 TOMAHAWK WIFI (MS-7D32)
BIOS Version - E7D32IMS.HD0
```

```
2.6808621 blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash (-13)
2.6808661 blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash (-13)
2.6808861 blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash (-13)
2.6809001 blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash (-13)
2.6809191 blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash (-13)
2.680931] blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash (-13)
```

Now my system gets freeze with this error and doesn't boot up.

But when I try with older kernel then it will start without giving the above error.

How to resolve this error for current default kernel?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the above problem. The problem is due to some kernel issue in Ubuntu 22.04. If you don't have older kernel like generic 5.15 generic download it using [this link](https://www.groovypost.com/howto/how-to-downgrade-the-kernel-in-ubuntu/).

After downloading kernel change the default kernel to the downloaded one using [this link](https://gist.github.com/chaiyujin/c08e59752c3e238ff3b1a5098322b363).

It works for me. It is definitely some ubuntu kernel issue rather than bios issue according to me.

Thanks